# Is HTTP response splitting/CRLF injection in PHP still possible?

Tags: php, html, security, xss, code-injection

I'd like to try and redirect my own website by passing something like:

`%0d%0aContent-Type:%20text/html%0d%0aHTTP/1.1%20200%20OK%0d%0aContent-Type:%20text/html%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Ccenter%3E%3Ch1%3EHacked%3C/h1%3E%3C/center%3E`

(taken from [this example](https://prakharprasad.com/crlf-injection-http-response-splitting-explained/)) into a url parameter. The PHP function I use for the redirect is the header() function:

```html
<?php
header('Location: ' .$_GET['url']);
?>
```

After noticing the injection didn't work and a warning message popping up stating that multiple headers were detected, I looked at the function documentation and noticed that response splitting in PHP has been fixed since version 5.1.2.

Is there another way of doing the injection I tried to do with current versions of PHP? I also read that adding a space after the CRLF (`%0a%0d%20`) worked in Internet Explorer up to PHP version 5.2. I tried this as well, but didn't work either.

Comment: Provided the website is using the `header` function, then no - as the function checks for linebreaks.

Comment: See also [PHP :: Bug #60227 :: header() cannot detect the multi-line header with CR(0x0D).](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60227)